# 'class_exists' creating infinite loop

Tags: php

The following code is creating an infinite loop:

```
$app->OBJ = (object) array(
        // SYSTEM OBJECTS
        'SCOPE'     => TRUE,
        'URI'       => TRUE,
        'Log'       => FALSE,
        // APPLICATION OBJECTS
        'User'      => TRUE,
        'Email'     => TRUE,
        'Files'     => TRUE,
    );

foreach ($app->OBJ as $obj => $bool) {
    if($bool){
        if(!class_exists($obj)) exit('Internal Error: Class \''.$obj.'\' not found.');
        ${strtoupper($obj)} = new $obj();
    }
}
```

But if I comment this line the loop stops:

```
// ${strtoupper($obj)} = new $obj();
```

All my class files are loaded, why is `class_exists` creating an infinite loop?

Comment: wrap the body of if with brackets {} and see real behavior.

Comment: what body are you referring to? @Maks3w

Comment: You are using assigning a new `$obj() ;` to `strtoupper($obj)` - so you are applying a function to what does not exist yet.